# How can I find a cell's location using the max function on a struct?

Tags: matlab

I have a struct with one field. I want to find the max value in the struct, but also know which row it is located in. How do I do this?

Currently I have:

> max(getfield(red2_mean, 'MeanIntensity'))

With red2_mean as the struct name, and MeanIntensity as the field.

This returns the correct maximum value, but I don't know which row (cell number?) it's in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand you fully, but if you have only a single fields why wont you try:

```
[val id]=max(red2_mean.MeanIntensity)
```

Comment: @Justin Then you probably have a struct array and need to wrap the input in `[` and `]`: `[val id]=max([red2_mean.MeanIntensity])`.

Comment: if you can give a minimal example, I'll be able to help you more. Just create some bogus struct that I can copy.

Comment: It was a struct array and the '[  ] ' helped. Thanks guys!